# Regexp to match 2 different possible inputs

Tags: regex, hive

I want to use one regexp to take the following 2 different inputs:

```
schema/table/col1,col2
schema/table
```

and have the output just be:

```
schema/table
```

I am using this in the Hive UDF regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index) where I have to give the index of the match.

I have tried using `^([^/]*/){2}|^.*` with index 0 and it gets almost what I want.

With input `schema/table/col1,col2` I get `schema/table/`, but I don't want the second `/`.

With input `schema/table` I get `schema/table`, which is what I want.

Also, "schema", "table" "col", etc are all placeholders. I don't want to hard code any text or text length.

Reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: what you have tried mate ?

Comment: @CodeManiac I have tried using `^([^/]*/){2}|^.*` with index 0 and it gets almost what I want.

With input `schema/table/col1,col2` I get `schema/table/`, but I don't want the second `/`.

With input `schema/table` I get `schema/table`, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate regex is: `(^[^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)`

This returns two capture groups with the respective values.

Comment: But I will never know what the actual schema or table names are, and I will never know their length.

Comment: See my edit. First group is your schema and the second one the name of the table.

Comment: `(^[^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)` works! I had gotten `^([^/]*/){1}[^_]+(?=/)|^.*` to work but mine seems overly complicated. I like yours better! Thanks!

Comment: We all get lost in the regex jungle fro time to time. :-D